# Laravel 5.8. Es posible pasar datos desde un comando a una vista?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo un comando en laravel que se está ejecutando y cada vez que sucede un evento debo pasar una variable a la vista. Intento hacer:

```
    $post = 'Soy un post';
    return View::make('carpeta.vista')->with('post', $post);
```

También intenté

```
    return view('carpeta.vista', [
        'post' => $post,
    ]);
```

Pero el comando no pasa mi variable a la vista. Cualquier aporte ayudaría, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si solo utilizas php laravel puedes tambien usar `compact`

```
return view('carpeta.vista', compact('post'));
```

en caso de que usas JS o Vuejs debes verificar si el request lo hacen por axios o ajax
de igual manera revisa bien la estructura de tus vistas y que la estes llamando e impirimiendo correctamente en la vista

Esta es la sintaxis que te comente

```
if( request()->wantsJson() ) // verifica si la peticion es de tipo ajax
        {
            return $post;
        }
```